# Showing that continuous and differentiable $s(t)$, with $s(0)=0$ and $s'(t)\leq 2ts(t)+\sqrt{s(t)}$ for $t>0$, is identically zero for $t\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Let $s:[0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$.

It also holds that $$s'(t)\leq 2ts(t)+\sqrt{s(t)}, \ \ t>0 \\ s(0)=0$$ Show that $s(t)=0, t\ge 0$.

Do we us some theorem, maybe Rolle or the mean value theorem?

$$$$

Do we have to check maybe the sign of $2ts(t)+\sqrt{s(t)}$ ? This depends on the value of $s(t)$, or not?

Comment: Try to work with the function $u(t) = \sqrt{s(t)}$. What can you say about $u'(t)$?

Comment: With $u(t)=\sqrt{s(t)}$ we have that $u'(t)=\frac{s'(t)}{2\sqrt{s(t)}} \Rightarrow s'(t)=2\sqrt{s(t)}u'(t)=2u(t)u'(t)$. 

Substituting in the given relation we get $2u(t)u'(t)\leq 2tu^2(t)+u(t)$. Can we divide by $u(t)$ ?  @HansEngler

Comment: If yes : Dividing by $u(t)$ we get $2u'(t)\leq 2tu(t)+1\Rightarrow u'(t)\leq tu(t)+1/2$. How could we continue? Do we solve that as a normal ode equation just with an inequality? @HansEngler

Comment: Can you solve $u'(t)=1/2$ ?

Comment: Do we solve the homogeneous part and the non homogeneous part? First $u'(t)\leq tu(t)$ and then $u'(t)\leq tu(t)+1/2$ ? @Empy2

Comment: Do we solve the homogeneous part and the non homogeneous part? First $u'(t)\leq tu(t)$ and then $u'(t)\leq tu(t)+1/2$ ? @HansEngler

Comment: As explained in the answer by @Gerd, there is a **non-zero** solution $s(t)$ and one cannot conclude that $s(t) = 0$ for all $t > 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Am I missing something? Set $s(t)=\frac{1}{4} \exp(t^2)\left(\int_0^t \exp(-\tau^2/2) d\tau \right)^2$ $(t \ge 0)$. Then $s(t) \ge 0$, $s(0)=0$ and
$$
s'(t)=\frac{t}{2} \exp(t^2)\left(\int_0^t \exp(-\tau^2/2) d\tau \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}\exp(t^2) 2 \int_0^t \exp(-\tau^2/2) d\tau \exp(-t^2/2)
$$
$$
=2ts(t)+ \frac{1}{2}\exp(t^2/2)\int_0^t \exp(-\tau^2/2) d\tau
$$
$$
=2ts(t)+ \sqrt{s(t)}
$$

Edit: The idea to find this solution: Consider the ODE $s'=2ts + \sqrt{s}$. Then substitute $u=\exp(-t^2)s$ to obtain $u'=\exp(-t^2/2)\sqrt{u}$. Separation of variables then leads to the maximal solution of the ivp for $u$ hence for $s$.

Comment: I agree :) but it would be nice if you explained how you arrived at this solution.

Comment: @Hans Engler I edited the answer.

Comment: You might have missed $s(t)=t^2/4$ obeys the inequality

Comment: @Empy2 Right. That's a simpler counterexample +1.